# Postfix Dovecot thousands of emails seem to come from local server to local mailbox

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot

I have been using this setup for many years [Workaround](https://workaround.org/)

I just updated my server to the latest guide (Buster) and it was working good for a month.

I have DMARC setup

```
v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; sp=none; rua=mailto:postmaster@example.org; ruf=mailto:postmaster@example.org; rf=afrf; pct=100; ri=86400
```

I have SPF setup. I understand that this is a soft fail.

```
v=spf1 mx a ip4:XX.XX.XX.XX/27 ~all
```

And I have DKIM setup as well

```
v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQE...public key
```

I have tested these with mxtoolbox.com and they seem to be fine.

My master.cf is

```
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

And my main.cf is

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.2.0/24

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.example.org
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mail.example.org, mail3.example.org, localhost.example.org, localhost
relayhost =
```

I have received hundreds of thousands of emails to a specific account from that account like this:

```
Return-Path: <nobody@mail.example.org>
Delivered-To: support_desk@example.org
Received: from mail.example.org
    by mail.example.org with LMTP
    id wD98AeFp/F8WUgAASGYJ/Q
    (envelope-from <nobody@mail.example.org>)
    for <support_desk@example.org>; Mon, 11 Jan 2021 10:08:17 -0500
Received: by mail.example.org (Postfix, from userid 65534)
    id 06C412449DA; Mon, 11 Jan 2021 08:11:36 -0500 (EST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=example.org;
    s=2020122201; t=1610370697; h=from:from:sender:reply-to:subject:subject:date:date:
     message-id:message-id:to:to:cc:mime-version:content-type:
     content-transfer-encoding:in-reply-to:references;
    bh=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=;
    b=kDMb7uDRl/dzTXWGMi75Cx0OgKvqDTgzuMgBD8bsFzDCAYFgd3csm78WFY2XoLjq30BqTD
    c3k4lwsvACLKhWK8L3j+l9AsX6lnJBzs7N7OBXWf6VN2U5Wdb3OSLjvyI20DOlwW/6sd94
    lRC446wHCsex4iP7XOJXRaJo4+bH7NY=
To: support_desk@example.org
Subject: Support [TICKET 1877258] [TICKET 1877259]
From: Archie Support <support@example.org>
Message-Id: <20210111131137.06C412449DA@mail.example.org>
Date: Mon, 11 Jan 2021 08:11:36 -0500 (EST)
```

Can anyone please help and let me know if there is an issue with my config? It seems that now my server is also listed on a couple of blacklists.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a loop. Someone connected and guessed an account that was an alias, that would then reply to the sender and forward the email to some other account.

All-in-all a good excuse to enjoy a 12-pack while reading mail logs...